# Find all beans that have a custom annotation

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm using Java EE on Wildfly 10, and want to create an annotation called `@WorkflowFinished` that has a method that it called when something happens.

I want to be able to have multiple `@Stateless` EJBs that are annotated with this, and when my business services finishes it should search for all EJBs with this annotation and call a method on them.

How do I go about this?  Something like this:

```
public void process(SomeBean b){
   b.doSomething();

   List<?> listOfAnnotatedBeans = getAnnotatedEJBs(WorkflowFinished.class);

   for(? ejb : listOfAnnotatedBeans){
      ejb.someMethod(b);
   }
}
```

How do I do this in an EJB context, **NOT Spring**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate through all the beans in the current "context" with a particular annotation or an array of annotations with something like this:

```
import com.some.WorkflowFinished;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral;

.
.
.

@Inject
BeanManager beanManager;
for (Bean<?> bean : beans) {

Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager
    .getBeans(Object.class,new AnnotationLiteral<WorkflowFinished>() {});
```

So that's probably a good basis for your getAnnotatedEJBs method.

Be aware that you'll need to set the annotation retention policy to RUNTIME.

Comment: That works OK, now how to I get my class from the `Bean<?>`.  If I cast the `bean` in the for loop to the interface that the class implements I get an exception, even though `bean.getBeanClass()` returns the correct class.  How can I get the actual class instance from the `Bean`?